# CLion won't compile on MacOS, why?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, clion

I recently downloaded CLion and wanted to start programming c++ on CLion. However, every time I can't run anything. I have a macbook m1 pro and macos big sur. This is the error message:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken CMake Error at /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):   The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/[myusername]/CLionProjects/untitled1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_8ef99/fast && 
    You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I already tried sudo xcodebuild -license and agreed, but still it doesn't work after a restart.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with CLion. it's CMake that failed to calls the compiler installed with Xcode. Have you installed Xcode command line developer tools? Check here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-macos.html#reqtools

After installing and accepting all the agreements, it's indeed a good advice to do Tools | CMake | Reset Cache and Reload Project

Answer (score 0):

Try and delete the generated cmake-build-debug directory and refresh cmake within CLion.